# share link with original image size on facebook using facebook api and php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I shared link on facebook using php sdk. I got image in facebook fixed size at post. But i want to original image size on my post. Below is my script.

```
<?php 
require_once('facebook.php');
$config = array(
'appId' => 'xxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxx',
'allowSignedRequest' => true // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
 );
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token= $facebook->getAccessToken();
if($user_id!='')
{
  try {
  $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array( 'access_token' => $access_token, 'message' => 'Omg escape Games', 'link' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/omgescape/', 'picture' => 'https://www.omgescape.com/images/Johnny-320x300-jpg.jpg', 'name' => 'Jane Maxwell', 'caption' => 'Play this', 'description' => 'Play games on OMG Escape' ));
echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Fan Page';
      } 
   catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
?>
```

When I share link through facebook api using php sdk, I got image like below.
[image]

But I want original image size in post. How to do that

Answer (score 0):

Images shared to Facebook via the API will always appear the same size (as per your screenshot). Facebook decides (using a complex algorithm) if the image should be bigger to users when viewing the Stream - usually this depends on the usefulness or engagement of the share.

Naturally, larger images will get better engagement, so this is exclusively decided by Facebook. If users share something to their timeline manually (e.g. by posting a image or link using the form on Facebook) the images tent to be larger as it's counted as an "organic" share - something the user explicitly did.